# How to load thousands of emoji Images & GIF into iPhone app using web services

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am developing an application & some how it is similar to “Hi-Art App”, in which i am showing thousands of emojis, in that some are PNG & some are GIF. Now i am downloading all images from server instead of storing them locally because it is project need. When i am downloading images using web service, it is taking too much downloading time & also taking too much memory. I have also tried to use “SDWebImageCache” but it is not working for GIF images. It is taking memory up to 1 GB, if all images get downloaded. I have also tried to use “YLGIFImage” but it is also not working effectively & some images are also not getting load.

Please any buddy help me to provide any optimum way without too much memory consumption & loading time to show thousand of images and gif from web server database.